# colored underline with vertical spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, boxes

How can I add a vertical spacing between the underline and other items by adjusting the `\colorunderline` command?

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\newsavebox\UnderlineBox
\newcommand\colorunderline[2][red]{%
        {\sbox\UnderlineBox{$#2$}%
        \rlap{\usebox\UnderlineBox}\color{#1}%
        \raisebox{-5pt}{\mbox{\rule[-\dp\UnderlineBox]{\wd\UnderlineBox}{3pt}}}%
        }%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c}
A\\
\colorunderline[red]{A}\\
A
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear in what context you're using this; the space below can be adjusted using ``\\[5pt]`` (or similar).

Comment: I want that the underline has some defined invisible border below the line which I can adjust? How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `\innercolorunderline` macro that does what you need, the list of arguments should be self-explanatory. I added a handier key-value interface with some examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\innercolorunderline}[4]{%
  % #1 = space above rule, #2 = space below rule, #3 = color, #4 = symbol
  \vtop{
    \offinterlineskip
    \sbox0{$#4$}
    \copy0
    \kern#1
    \hbox{\color{#3}\vrule height 3pt width \wd0}
    \kern#2
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { gabriel/colorunderline }
 {
  color .tl_set:N  = \l_gabriel_colorunderline_color_tl,
  color .initial:n = red,
  above .dim_set:N = \l_gabriel_colorunderline_above_dim,
  above .initial:n = 2pt,
  below .dim_set:N = \l_gabriel_colorunderline_below_dim,
  below .initial:n = 0pt,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\colorunderline}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { gabriel/colorunderline } { #1 }
  \gabriel_colorunderline:VVVn
    \l_gabriel_colorunderline_above_dim
    \l_gabriel_colorunderline_below_dim
    \l_gabriel_colorunderline_color_tl
    { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \gabriel_colorunderline:nnnn \innercolorunderline
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gabriel_colorunderline:nnnn { VVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}[t]{c}
A\\
\colorunderline{A}\\
A
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}[t]{c}
A\\
\colorunderline[color=green]{A}\\
A
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}[t]{c}
A\\
\colorunderline[above=6pt]{A}\\
A
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}[t]{c}
A\\
\colorunderline[color=red,above=6pt,below=6pt]{A}\\
A
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: favbulous! even if I dont understand the code

Comment: @Gabriel The first macro just stacks two boxes, taking as reference point the top one. Some customizable space is inserted between the boxes and at the bottom. The rest is just defining a key-value interface.

Comment: why does that not work in inline math?

Comment: the spacing seems to be wrong in inline math?

Comment: @Gabriel I forgot `\offinterlineskip`! Fixed.